# Have a synchronous handler and an asynchronous handler

Tags: c#, mediator, mediatr

Please see the synchronous code below:

```
public class PersonHandler : IRequestHandler<Person, Person>
    {
        public Task<Person> Handle(Person request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.ID = 1;
            request.Name = "Brian";
            request.Age = 53;
            return Task.FromResult(request);
        }
    }
```

and the calling code below:

```
var response2 = mediator.Send(new Person());
```

This works as expected.  Please see the asynchronous code below:

```
public class PersonHandlerAsync : IRequestHandler<Person, Person>
    {
        public async Task<Person> Handle(Person request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.ID = 1;
            request.Name = "Brian";
            request.Age = 53;
            var result = await Task.FromResult(request);
            await Task.Delay(30000);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and the calling code below:

```
var response = Task.Run(() => mediator.Send(new Person()));
```

This code works as expected.

Is it possible to have two handlers for the same class (Person) i.e. one synchronous and the other asynchronous? If I put both handler classes in my code, then both the mediator.send lines i.e. `mediator.Send(new Person());` and `Task.Run(() => mediator.Send(new Person()));` call the synchronous method.

How can I tell mediatr, which handler class to use? i.e. PersonHandler for synchronous calls and PersonHandlerAsync for asynchronous calls.

Comment: what version of Mediatr are you using?:

Comment: @Alex, 4.0.1.  It does not appear to have IAsyncRequestHandler as described in the documentation here: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki (bottom of page).

Comment: @Alex, do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it how you've specified.

> Declare whatever flavor of handler you need - sync, async or cancellable async. From the IMediator side, the interface is async-only, designed for modern hosts.

However, one workaround would be to create a `PersonRequest` and `PersonRequestAsync` class, inherited from `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

//sync request
public class PersonRequest : Person, IRequest<Person>
{ }

//async request
public class PersonRequestAsync : Person, IRequest<Person>
{ }
```

Then, your handlers could look something like this:

```
public class PersonHandler : IRequestHandler<PersonRequest, Person>
{
    public Task<Person> Handle(Person request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.ID = 1;
        request.Name = "Brian";
        request.Age = 53;
        return Task.FromResult(request);
    }
}
```

And your `async` handler as follows:

```
public class PersonHandlerAsync : IRequestHandler<PersonRequestAsync, Person>
{
    public async Task<Person> Handle(PersonRequestAsync request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.ID = 1;
        request.Name = "Brian";
        request.Age = 53;

        //not sure what this is? Hopefully it's just here for demo purposes!
        var result = await Task.FromResult(request);

        await Task.Delay(30000);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This effectively ties `PersonRequestAsync` to `PersonHandlerAsync`

Comment: Thanks.  In the documentation there is reference to IAsyncRequestHandler and the SendAsync method.  However, I cannot find them.  Are they now obsolete?

Comment: Yeah, there certainly used to be - I think this was removed in v4 - but looks like the docs haven't been fully updated

Comment: I assume this would be impossible with iterator interface? i.e with `yield return`ing with `IEnumerable<,>` return signatured handler?